# Upgrading to select2 v4: make matcher compatible

Tags: jquery-select2-4

I have a matcher from an older version of select2, and I need to get it to work in select2 v4. select2 v4 has changed the matcher function, and offers a compatibility module with which you can wrap your old matcher. The module is included in the "full" version of select2, and is listed under "select2/compat/matcher". I just don't know how to read it well enough to utilize it and wrap my old matcher, which looks like this:

```
           matcher: function (term, text) {
           term = term.toUpperCase().replace('SAINT', 'ST. C').replace(' ', '').replace('.', '');
           text = text.toUpperCase().replace('SAINT', 'ST. C').replace(' ', '').replace('.', '');

           return text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase()) >= 0;

       }
```

I have done some reading about AMD and modules, but it's still a bit too advanced for me to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I found some example code on the select2 site:

```
        $.fn.select2.amd.require(['select2/compat/matcher'], function (oldMatcher) {
        $(".county_id").select2({
            placeholder: "Enter a county name or select from list",
            allowClear: true,
            matcher: oldMatcher(matchStart)
        })
```

where matchStart refers to the old match function.